# Problem with SetValue method in ArcGIS 9.3

Tags: python, arcgis-9.3

I am trying to make a python script for ArcGIS 9.3. I have a problem with the SetValue method. I try to use it in a very simple code but it still doesn't work : No error is return but my field is not populate. The code is the following :

```
import arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

gp.workspace = r"Z:\PPR\PPR76\Tentative Macro Amelioration MNT"

try:

    input = gp.GetParameterAsText(0)
    field = "TEST"

    rows = gp.UpdateCursor(input)
    row = rows.Next()
    while row:
        expression = 3
        row.SetValue( field , expression)
        row = rows.Next()
except:
    print gp.GetMessages(2)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    rows = gp.UpdateCursor(input)
    row = rows.Next()
    while row:
        expression = 3
        row.SetValue( field , expression)
        row = rows.Next()
```

Try

```
    rows = gp.UpdateCursor(input)
    for row in iter(rows.next, None):
        expression = 3
        row.SetValue(field, expression)
        rows.updateRow(row)
```

Basically you forgot to call [the `updateRow` method](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=UpdateCursor_method). That `iter()` trick isn't necessary, it just makes the code a little easier to read and lets you use a `for` loop.

Comment: I added : rows.updateRow(row) before row=rows.Next() and it worked.

Thanks